# Gesture-Controlling Javascript InfoVis Toolkit via C# (Kinect SDK)

Tags: c#, javascript, kinect, kinect-sdk, infovis

I've been running around the web for a while now looking for a solution to this problem, but I'm quite disheartened by now to find something that will fit all of my requirements. So here goes.

I'm trying to build a desktop application that uses the Kinect for Windows sensor to control a visualization of digital library (as in, the place you go to for books) assets. I'm quite versed in using the official MS Kinect SDK and already have a neat utility framework for prototyping at hand, so I'd obviously love to make use of it. This plus the desktop app theme of things says the whole shebang will need to be in C#, which is fine by me.

On the other hand, the visualization part already exists and looks gorgeous, but it's JavaScript (and specifically, JIT i.e. javascript infovis toolkit). It has all the bells and whistles I need and it's neatly animated. Also, I'm a noob at JavaScript.

The point is, how do I avoid rewriting either one into the other's language while still allowing them to talk at runtime?

So, do you know any way to either 
A) embed a JIT visualization (e.g. radial tree visualization) in a windows application in a way that allows me to manipulate the graph at runtime from a C# class (e.g. selecting a new node to be animated into focus) or 
B) send C# events to JS to react to gesture input at runtime? Is this something ASP.NET can do?

I have a feeling the result will be a weird mix of desktop and web technology, but any pointers to the right sort of technology is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should look at this projects about using Kinect with JavaScript:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/kinectedbrowser/

http://kinesis.io/

Comment: Kinesis looks quite promising, will check it out. Thanks! I'll leave the question open for more suggestions, though. If there aren't any better, I'll close this up next week.

Comment: The new Kinect SDK 1.8 has more integrated functionality with JavaScript. I tried an example using WebSockets using C#.Net, but it required Windows 8.